separating surface in manifold
Suppose $M$ is an orientable 3-manifold, $\Sigma$ is a closed embedded orientable surface in $M$. Suppose the inclusion map induces a surjective map from $\pi_1(\Sigma)\rightarrow \pi_1(M)$. It seems to me that $\Sigma$ must separate the manifold $M$. But the paper I read says it might not separate. Is there any example? If $\Sigma$ is noncompact complete, does it make any difference?

What is the paper in question?
